# Ghostscript rasterizer.GetPage returns null c#

Tags: c#, .net, null, ghostscript

I´m trying to get an image from PDF with Ghostcript.NET in C#. I have installed Ghostscript dll already (both 32 and 64 bit) and added the reference in the proyect. I´ve just taken the example for the web and it gives me an error (img was null) and i don´t know why. This is the code:

```
`using System;
using Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer;
using System.IO;
using Ghostscript.NET;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace StackOverflowExample
{
    class Program
    {
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int desired_dpi = 96;

            string inputPdfPath = @"C:\Users\orubio\Documents\Pruebas\test.pdf";
            string outputPath = @"C:\Users\orubio\Documents\Pruebas\";

            GhostscriptVersionInfo gvi = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gsdll32.dll");

            using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
            {
                rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, gvi, false);

                for (var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
                {
                    var pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, string.Format("Page-{0}.png", pageNumber));

                    var img = rasterizer.GetPage(desired_dpi, pageNumber);
                    img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);

                    Console.WriteLine(pageFilePath);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}`
```

[img null error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C55Ao.png)

Ty everyone :D

Comment: Please add the specific error to your post, rather than include it in an image (in case that image link ever gets broken and for readability). 

You need to debug this line further: `var img = rasterizer.GetPage(desired_dpi, pageNumber);` Your error is saying `img` is null, so you need to debug to figure out why your `rasterizer` isn't returning your page.

Comment: You would probably get more feedback if you tag the question with Ghostscript.NET rather than Ghostscript.....